# How can I make good use of tumble dryer lint?

Tags: cleaning, clothing, trash

Every time I clean out the lint trap of the tumble dryer, I keep wondering how to make good use of this by-product of our clothes washing. Rather than throw it away, I've taken to putting it in a bag. It seems a shame to waste it, but unless I find a good use for it soon, I will have to resign myself to that. What creative uses can it be put to?

Answer (score 3):

You can keep old ice cream tub in a cupboard near the tumble dryer for lint recycling purposes and simply chuck the lint in there each time when clean out the trap. You can re use them for following purpose.

- Eco-friendly waterproof firelighters: The very flammability of lint can be used if a rapid fire is required.
- Pet bedding: Burrowing pets love a roll in the lint and so you can use it.
- Play clay:Lint clay is fun to make and even more fun to mess around with on a rainy afternoon.
- Packaging for breakables: Clean, soft and flexible lint is ideal for protecting fragile objects during posting or a house move.
- Compost material:Any purely natural fibre lint can be composted.

Comment: I'm curious about the title of your first use, "Eco-friendly waterproof firelighters".  What is meant by "waterproof"?  Are you implying that they will burn even when wet?

Comment: Many modern fabrics are made to not catch fire as easy these days and the lint will also not burn as it would have done in the past.

Comment: I wouldn't use the lint as pet bedding, the super-fine and short fibers can be bad for their lungs and if ingested. Plus there can be detergent residue in the fibers. Also note that dryer lint contains a lot of very small dusty particles, which if used for padding objects, should either be wrapped in plastic bags or the fragile items themselves should be wrapped prior to padding. I have to downvote because the pet suggestion is actually harmful for the animals.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily create a throw pillow (just 2 rectangles of fabric sewn together) and use that as stuffing. With a little fancier shape, you could create a stuffed animal for a kid and fill it with dryer lint.

However, you should research dryer lint allergens before creating either of these. It could be that a lint-filled pillow makes people sneeze!

Comment: In my experience lint particles are small, like dust.  It will quickly work its way through fabric.  Any kid of mine playing with a pillow or stuffed animal filled with lint would be shrouded in a dust cloud.

Comment: I made a teddy from an old tshirt and stuffed it with dryer lint. It's no good. It went all lumpy and irritating  dust seeps out.

Answer (score 0):

Vermiculture. Dryer Lint makes an excellent bedding for worms who compost everything and create nice fertile castings for your garden.

Answer (score 0):

Make paper from the lint.   A search will uncover several sites with instructions how to do it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12299)

Comment: If making paper doesn't answer the question of what to do with the lint, then none of the other answers are either.  You have a better suggestion???

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to throw it outside, for birds to make nests of it.

It´s quite good as isolation, so you can use it to have one temperature inside of something and another outside. That could be an isolating bag (hot/cold food/beverages), a birdhouse or sewing it into pockets and make your own sleeping bag.